# Rails: attribute_changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that has an `amount` and I'm tracking to see if this amount is changed with a `Model.amount_changed?` with a `before_save` which works fine but when I check to see `amount_was` and `amount_change?` it only returns the updated amount not the previous amount. And all this is happening before it is save. It knows when the attribute is changed but it will not return the old value.

Ideas?

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save  :status_amount, :if => :status_amount_changed

def status_amount_changed
  if self.amount_changed? && !self.new_record?
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

def status_amount
    title = "Changed Amount"
    description = "to #{self.amount_was} changed to #{self.amount} units"
    create_reservation_event(title, description)
end

def create_reservation_event(title, description)
    Event.create(:reservation => self, :sharedorder => self.sharedorder, :title => title,     :description => description, :retailer => self.retailer )
end

end
```

Comment: I found https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html useful in understanding the Rails ActiveRecord `_changed?` functions.  Someone mentioned it in a comment on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838313/rails-changed-method-is-always-false).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to keep track of changes in your model Rails provides ["Dirty Objects"](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html).
E.g. Your model has a `name` attribute:

```
my_model = MyModel.find(:first)
my_model.changed?  # it returns false

# You can Track changes to attributes with my_model.name_changed? accessor
my_model.name  # returns  "Name"
my_model.name = "New Name"
my_model.name_changed? # returns true

# Access previous value with name_was accessor
my_model.name_was  # "Name"

# You can also see both the previous and the current values, using name_change
my_model.name_change  #=> ["Name", "New Name"]
```

If you want to store the old value inside your database, you can use:

1. the model attribute `amount`
2. the method **_was** on the above attribute in other words: `amount_was` that retrieve the value of **amount** before the change.

You can save both during the `update_attributes` call. 
Otherwise, if you don't need the `amount_was` history, you  can just use two instance variables.

If you need somthing more, like tracking your model history, Rails has a nice dedicated plugin.
As for other nice topics Ryan Bates speak about I [here: Railscasts #177](http://railscasts.com/episodes/177-model-versioning)

Comment: amount is the attribute, _was is the method to find the before changed value. Same method. I saw the railscasts.

Comment: @s84 - In Rails 4 (not sure of 3), calling the following would NOT work: `Person.first.city_id_was.state`. Instead, you need to do: `City.find(Person.first.city_id_was).state`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `*_was` call to get the old value:

```
p m.amount_was if m.amount_changed?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another vertual attribute in your module

attr_accessor :initial_amount

and when you are loading data from DB, fill the initial_amount with amount

then you can check

(initial_amount == amount ? true : false)

cheers,
sameera