# rails changed? method is always false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to check in my model if a checkbox value was changed or not. If it was changed I want my method `set_ip_setting` to run in `before_save` but my `x` variable is always coming back as false even if I change the value. Why is it coming back as always false? I don't see what I am doing wrong

```
before_save :set_ip_setting, if: :check_my_ip
```

```
def check_my_ip
    x = self.sip.my_ip_changed?
    is_ip = self.sip.my_ip
    if x == true && is_ip == true
     return false
   elsif x == false && is_ip == true
     return false
  elsif x == true
     return true
   end 
end
```

```
def set_ip_setting
    if self.sip.try(:my_ip) == true 
      sip.nat = "yes"
      sip.invite = "yes"
    end
  end
```

*****EDITED*****
I got my desired outcome by using `previous_changes` method but I think there is a cleaner way but here is what worked out for me

```
  def check_my_ip
    x = self.sip.previous_changes[:my_ip]
    off_to_on = [false, true]
    on_to_off = [true, false]
    is_ip = self.sip.my_ip ? 1 : 0
    if x.nil? && is_ip == 1
      return false
    elsif x == on_to_off
      return false
    end
    return true
  end
```

Comment: What is this `my_ip_changed?` method?

Comment: can you show us model class and controller when passing the checkbox value?

Comment: @jvillian, looks like the model has a `my_ip` column, and this is utilizing methods from ActiveModel::Dirty 
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: @kbob, have you tried writing any puts statements in the method to confirm the error is that x is false, and not that your conditions are behaving differently than expected?

Comment: @ianroot I have put in debug statements `Rails.logger.debug "option #{x}"` which confirmed it was always false, I didn't include them here as I did not think it was needed for the question

Comment: @ianroot Thank you for the link to ActiveModel/Dirty.html.  That was very useful in understanding Rails's Active Record way of thinking, even though technically, it describes a parallel implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you do not write `if x == true`. In Ruby, `true` and `false` are distinct values. For example, `1 == true` is `false`.

Instead, simply check `if x` or `if !x`.

```
def check_my_ip
  # Note that an explicit `self` is not necessary except when setting a value.
  x = sip.my_ip_changed?
  is_ip = sip.my_ip

  if x && is_ip
    return false
  elsif !x && is_ip
    return false
  elsif x
    return true
  end 
end

def set_ip_setting
  if self.sip.try(:my_ip)
    sip.nat = "yes"
    sip.invite = "yes"
  end
end
```

Your logic can be simplified, and implicit return used.

```
def check_my_ip
  x = sip.my_ip_changed?
  is_ip = sip.my_ip

  if is_ip
    false
  elsif x
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you but this does not explain or tell me why my `x` is always `false` which is where the problem is.

Comment: @kbob I can't tell you that without seeing `my_ip_changed?` and `previous_changes` and in general what `self.sip` is.

Comment: yea, i think we need to know more about the form and the model to find the problem